# Using Icons Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, icons, asset-pipeline

I love font awesome but what is the best way to use other icons (custom made ones, small SVG files etc, one found on other sites) in RoR application? Where should these icons be placed and what is the proper  helper method to use on the icons?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that this question has something to do with Rails. AFAIK, this is accomplished with CSS, like this:

html:

```
<div class="item_buy">
  <a href="#"></a>
</div>
```

css:

```
.offers_carousel .item_buy a::before {
    background: url("../images/icons.png") no-repeat scroll -91px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 22px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -9px;
    margin-top: -11px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 17px;
}
```

Also, not sure if all browsers display SVG images. What I get from designers is usually JPEG or PNG.